# Radio Button, Text Area and Input check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with all the input fields as class `item`. When I click submit, it checks, with the following function if all values are filled in.

```
$.each($(".items"),function(i,e){
    // loop through all the items
    if(e.value == "" || !$("input[name='"+e.name+"']:radio:checked").length)
        if(error.indexOf(e.title) === -1)
            error += e.title + "<br/>";
    });
```

This form comprises of text areas, radio boxes and normal text input fields. It returns all the radio boxes not filled in, as well as all the text inputs not filled in. But then it also returns ALL the text areas, regardless of whether it's filled in or not.

I first thought it was because I specified it to check the value, but it seems the value check does in fact check text areas, so it can't be that.

Could anyone assist me in making it return only empty elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used a combination of JBRTRND and Florian Margaine's answers as neither wanted to work 100% correctly.

I just put this here incase someone is stuck on the same issue. I in no way take credit for ANY of the help I received from them and I'm really thankful for it.

This is how I fixed it:

```
$.each($(".items"),function(){
    // loop through all the items
        // and alert the value
        if ( this.type == 'radio' && !$("input[name='"+this.name+"']:radio:checked").length) {
            if(error.indexOf(this.title) === -1)
                error += this.title + "<br/>";
        }
        else if ( this.value === '' ) {
            if(error.indexOf(this.title) === -1)
                error += this.title + "<br/>";
        }
    });
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out :) Accept your answer then, it will make it go to the top and help people visiting this page.

Answer (score 3):

```
$.each( $( '.items' ), function() {
    if ( ( this.type === 'checkbox' || this.type === 'radio' ) && !this.checked ) {
        // Go
    }
    else if ( this.value === '' ) {
        // Do your stuff
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, it seems there is no other choice but to separate the cases.

Comment: yep, this is more clearer to me. / also I guess for the text_area maybe need to check the this.text ??

Comment: @zinking No need to check the textareas, it won't pass the `this.nodeName === 'INPUT'` check.

Comment: This doesn't pass any textareas if they are empty... it needs to check the text areas for emptiness too.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question then.

Comment: It should return ALL empty elements. My issue at the moment is that it returns all the textareas whether they contain text or not.

I'd like to help you rep whore period, so if you could update this answer, I'll upvote and accept! :P

Comment: Upvoted your answer as it also works, but I'm running with JBRTRND's answer. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: It doesn't return radio buttons... EDIT: I keep confusing myself with checkboxes and radio buttons.

Comment: Heh, I guess it needs separate checks.

Comment: @DarkRanger Edited. It's ugly though, I'm sorry I couldn't find a better solution.

Comment: I guess this is why libraries such as jQuery validate exist.

Comment: This edit brought it very close to what it should be. The only issue was that it checked each and every input with class items, so because only 1 of the four radio buttons in each 'group' was selected, it would return false on the first radio button and thus not pick up that it WAS in fact selected.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each($('.items'),function(i,elem){
    if( ($(elem).attr('type') == 'radio' || $(elem).attr('type') == 'checkbox') && !$(elem).is(':checked') ) {
               // RADIOS AND CHECKBOXES EMPTY
    } else if( $(elem).val().length == 0 ) {
              // INPUTS TYPE TEXT AND TEXTAREA EMPTY
    }
});
```

Comment: Still returns all textareas and not only the empty ones.

Comment: Thanks!! I just needed to change `$(elem).attr('type') == 'checkbox'` to `$(elem).attr('type') == 'radio` and add another parenthesis at the end of the if statement and it worked.

Comment: actually, I'm wrong, this doesn't work... it still returns all the radio boxes...